# How to compute $K(X\times S^2)$ using $\Omega ^2 BU\simeq BU\times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, k-theory, topological-k-theory

I'm reading "Algebraic Topology from a Homotopical Viewpoint."
The exercise 9.5.14 of it is as follows:

Deduce from the Bott periodicity theorem (in this book it means $\Omega ^2 BU\simeq BU\times \mathbb{Z}$) that $K(X\times S^2)$ is isomophic to the free module over the ring $K(X)$ with two generators $1$ and $L-1$.
Here $L$ denotes the pullback of the canonical line bundle over $S^2\cong CP^1$.

It seems that this is a standard approach for proving the Bott periodicity, but in this book one proves it by constructing the quasifibration $BU\times \mathbb{Z}\to E\to U$ where E is a contractible space.
I think it's not very difficult to prove that $K(X\times S^2)\cong K(X)\oplus K(X)$ using $\tilde{K}(X\times Y)\cong \tilde{K}(X)\oplus \tilde{K}(Y)\oplus \tilde{K}(X\wedge Y)$, but I have no idea how to find the generator.

What might be the answer authors intended?

Comment: I've just found the similar post on mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92247/weak-bott-periodicity-vs-strong-bott-periodicity , and it seems a little difficult to prove this... Or am I misunderstanding the situation (or question)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's at least what I imagine how the authors wanted the solution to start.  Recall that $K$-theory is "represented", i.e., $$K(X) \cong [X_+, BU \times \mathbb{Z}].$$  So,
\begin{align*}
K(X \times S^2) &\cong [(X \times S^2)_+, BU \times \mathbb{Z}] \\ &\cong [(X_+ \wedge S^2) \vee X_+, BU \times \mathbb{Z}] \\ &\cong [X_+ \wedge S^2, BU \times \mathbb{Z}] \oplus [X_+, BU \times \mathbb{Z}].
\end{align*}

The second summand is a copy of $K(X)$, generated by $1$, as you can check using the projection $X \times S^2 \to X$.  The first summand is trickier.  By adjunction and then the form of Bott periodicity you stated, we have $$[X_+ \wedge S^2, BU \times \mathbb{Z}] \cong [X_+, \Omega^2(BU \times \mathbb{Z})] \cong [X_+, BU \times \mathbb{Z}] \cong K(X).$$

To identify the generator, you need to know something about the map that implements the Bott isomorphism $BU \times \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\sim} \Omega^2 BU$.  For example, you might know that it's represented by tensoring with $L$ (or perhaps $L - 1$).  You might get away with just knowing $L$ generates $K(S^2)$ or $\pi_2 BU$.

Once you know this, the conclusion of the problem follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think is a fast way to identify the generator of $K(S^2)$?

Comment: It really depends on what you already know/what you're willing to use.  For example, vector bundles on $S^2$ are classified by their rank $n$ and the homotopy class of the clutching function on the equatorial circle in $[S^1, GL_n \mathbb{C}] \cong \mathbb{Z}$, where the isomorphism can be identified with the first Chern class.   Given this, it suffices to recall that $c_1(L)$ is a generator of $H^2(S^2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it anyway.

Comment: I have one more question. How do you show the second isomorphism in the second expression? I tried to show the homotopy equivalence $(X\times S^2)_+\simeq (X_+\wedge S^2)\vee X_+$ but I couldn't.

Comment: We have $(X \times S^2)_+ \cong X_+ \wedge S^2_+ \cong X_+ \wedge (S^2 \vee S^0) \cong (X_+ \wedge S^2) \vee (X_+ \wedge S^0) \cong (X_+ \wedge S^2) \vee X_+$.  It might be more convincing to draw pictures, though.

Comment: I understood. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

$(X \times S^2)_{+}$ is in general not homotopy equivalent to
$(X_{+} \wedge S^2) \vee X_{+}$.

Just take $X:= \{x_{1}, x_{2} \}$:

Then $(X \times S^2)_{+}$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $S^2$ with a disjoint basepoint.

And $(X_{+} \wedge S^2) \vee X_{+}$ is $S^2 \vee S^2$ and two disjoint points.

These two spaces are obviously not homotopy equivalent.